# Saving encrypted SVN password in IntelliJ Idea on Linux

Tags: linux, svn, encryption, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea (Ultimate 9.0.3) on Linux at work, and our VCS is Subversion.

Idea proposes to store my SVN password but then tells me it is unable to store the password encrypted, and asks if I want to store it in plain text. Well, no. This is on an Ubuntu 10.04 install with Gnome Keyring available.

Any hints how I could convince Subversion and Idea to work securely together?

Comment: This [blog](http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/07/subversion-16-security-improvements.html) details the possible options you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to vote for [Linux/OS X Subversion credentials working only when stored in plaintext](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-56464) bug in the IDEA issue tracker.